# Click event in blank area of TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview, contextmenu

To determine the content of my context menu I need to detect when the user clicks into the blank area of a treeview.
But, neither the `Click` nor the `MouseClick` events fire.
Is it possible to achieve the desired functionality by deriving from `TreeView`?
If not, what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the MouseDown event, that fires even in the empty area.

```
private void treeView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // MessageBox.Show("treeView1_MouseClick");
}

private void treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // MessageBox.Show("treeView1_Click");
}

private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("treeView1_MouseDown");
}
```